# How do I send a broadcast from my Application to whichever Activity is currently open?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I've tried a bunch of different approaches and unfortunately I'm still confused on the nature of the Intent that I'm passing into my broadcast so was hoping for a bit of guidance...

I have an Application that needs to send broadcasts and the intended recipients to these are whichever Activity of my app is currently running.

So... my broadcast currently looks like this (I'm still unclear on what the point of the class definition is here... am I meant to be targeting something in particular?) but it's not being heard in the Activities.

My Application is currently attempting to send a broadcast like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(
getPackageName() + ".FOO");//FOO is one of the 7 or so possible Activities that are in the overall app... I don't *want to name it perse, I just don't know what to replace it with 
intent.putExtra("com.mything.somethingSpecial", "TIME TO PARTY");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Then in my various activities I have a local BroadcastReciever like so:

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //do stuff
   };
}
```

and the onResume , onPause stuff...

```
@Override
public void onPause{
  this.unregisterReceiver(this.receiver);
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
   super.onResume();
   IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
   filter.addAction("com.mything.somethingSpecial");
   this.registerReceiver(this.receiver, filter);

 }
```

So, at the moment, the broadcast is being sent (I think... I don't know how to verify that either, I guess, but no exceptions are raised, so, I'm guessing it's going out), but the activity isn't entering that block of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("com.mything.somethingSpecial.Broadcast"); 
 intent.putExtra("com.mything.somethingSpecial", "TIME TO PARTY");
 sendBroadcast(intent);
```

and then

```
@Override
public void onPause{
  this.unregisterReceiver(this.receiver);
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
super.onResume();
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("com.mything.somethingSpecial.Broadcast");
this.registerReceiver(this.receiver, filter); 
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer... is there anything explicitly better about the way you're doing it than the way I'm doing it (in my answer above)? What's the advantage to specifying a `String` in the Intent invocation?

Comment: Its exactly same :) I answered at the same time when you were answering, so I didn't saw your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ah!

I figured it out... answering for posterity...

changed the Broadcast to

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setAction("com.mything.somethingSpecial");
 sendBroadcast(intent);
```

and bingo.